# Call one salt-stack script from another

Tags: salt-stack

What is the best way to have one salt sls file call another? Does salt provide a way to do this or do I need a workaround?

The context is that I have one salt script installing Apache Tomcat, and I would like to make another script copy out the webapps into a temporary directory, run the installation script, then afterwards copy the webapps back in. I know I could put this in one .sls file, but I would like to keep them separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include other sls files. Example:

```
tomcat/install.sls
apps.sls
```

In apps.sls, you just put:

```
#save_webapps
[...]

include:
- tomcat.install

[...]
#restore_webapps
```

It should work as is, but you can use requisites (require and require_in) to make sure your states executes in the order you want.